# Read Columns depending on their values using TextFieldParser

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I'm reading a CSV File using TextFieldParser in C#. I could manage to read a simple CSV file but this CSV file has multiple formatting styles depending on the First Column name, like this:

```
>>Name, Age, Location,
"Joe","29","NY"
"Maggie", "25", "NJ"
>>City, State, Population
"New York", "NY","8.49"
```

THE CSV HAS MANY MORE TYPES OF INFORMATION.

I'm trying to read the columns depending on their formatting, but it only reads the column names. How can I make it read only the target formatting type? The part of the code that does that is here:

```
while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
   if (parser.ReadFields().Contains(">>Name"))
   {
      header = true;
      string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

      if (header)
      {
         foreach (var val in fields)
         {
            dt.Columns.Add(val);
         }

         header = false;
         continue;
      }

      dt.Rows.Add(fields);
   }
   else {};
}
```

**EDIT:**

The ">>" symbols are a flag to say when I have column names.

Comment: What is a real sample file?  It's not clear what ">>Title, can be ignored
>>Name, Age, Location,
"Joe","29","NY"" means. Is that the real text or is it mixed up with your comments?

Comment: What is the parser variable? you could also use the [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/) library to accomplish this task.

Comment: Also, your `if` is only entered if `parser.ReadFields().Contains(">>Name")`. So the following `if(header)` is pontless because it's always the header. Next issue: `parser.ReadFields()` will advance the reader to the next line, so when you execute it twice you will get the second line's fields not the header fields.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I removed the Title, apologies for that. When the characters ">>" are in the beginning of the line, it means this line is a header. The values after this line will be the rows of the column.

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk:: using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))

Comment: Could it be a problem that you have a comma in the end of the first line?

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk, unfortunately the first line does have a comma in the original csv file

Comment: Did you set a delimeter using the `SetDelimiters(",")` method?

Comment: Why do you have such a strange CSV file? You have multiple headers and between these "header"-lines you have _data-blocks_?  Does that means that both, Joe and Maggie live in New York?

Comment: @TimSchmelter The information contained in this file is not necessarily related to each other. Is there a way in C# to generate multiple CSV files from this file so it's easier to parse it afterwards? The flag would be always the characters ">>". Unfortunately I cannot control the generation of the original CSV file so I'm stuck with it.

Comment: @Dalek: so actually you want to generate multiple `DataTables` from this file. The `>>` indicates the next table?

Comment: @Dalek: i ask if you want to generate multiple `DataTables` and you answer "no, i want to parse a single file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if this file contains data of multiple tables, every next table's header starts with `>>`. You could fill a `DataSet` in this way:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(@"C:\Temp\textfile.txt"))
{
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true; // <--- !!!
    string[] lineFields;
    while ((lineFields = parser.ReadFields()) != null)
    {
        if (lineFields[0].StartsWith(">>"))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn[] cols = lineFields
                .Where(t => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t))
                .Select(t => new DataColumn(t.Trim(' ', '>')))
                .ToArray();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(cols);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
        else if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable lastTable = ds.Tables[ds.Tables.Count - 1];
            lineFields = lineFields
                .Where(t => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t))
                .Take(lastTable.Columns.Count)
                .Select(t => t.Trim())
                .ToArray();
            lastTable.Rows.Add(lineFields);
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with your sample data. A `DataSet` with following two `DataTables` is generated:

Table1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify the delimeter using the [SetDelimeters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.setdelimiters(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
{
    parser.SetDelimiters(",");
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] results = parser.ReadFields();
        if (results[0].StartsWith(">>"))
        {
            // headers
        }
        else
        {
            // data
        }
    }
}
```