# What is the best way to ignore columns while reading a CSV in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, csv

So I read a large CSV file and it might look something like

```
"Intelligent Mail barcode","Sack and Pa","Opt. Endorsement Line","Label ","NAME","COMPANY","DELADDR","CITY","ST","ZIP"
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","T1  P1","******AUTO**MIXED AADC 403","xxxx","xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx","xxxxx","xxxx","xxxxx"
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","T1  P1","******AUTO**MIXED AADC 403","xxxx","xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxx","xx","xxxxx"
```

I want to be able to remove the first 4 columns in this case. So Intelligent Mail, Sack and Pa, Opt. Endorse, and Label1 would be ignored and the data associated with them would also be ignored or blank.

So the output would be like

```
"NAME","COMPANY","DELADDR","CITY","ST","ZIP"
"xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx","xxxxx","xxxx","xxxxx"
"xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxx","xx","xxxxx"
```

How can I accomplish this? Looking for the easiest way to do this.

Here is how I read the CSV currently:

```
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileSaveLocation))
        {
            string line;
            header = reader.ReadLine();

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.Append(line);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of parsing the file yourself with `ReadLine` I'd suggest that an easier way to do this would be to use a library such as LINQtoCSV to handle serialisation between your CSV file and a POCO class.  There's an example on the documentation here -  https://www.codeproject.com/articles/25133/linq-to-csv-library

Comment: You should find a proven CSV parser rather than write your own.  There are many out there, like [Light and Fast CSV Parser](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823670/Csharp-Light-and-Fast-CSV-Parser) or [KBCsv](https://github.com/kentcb/KBCsv)

Comment: Wow thanks guys, I will take a look at these asap.

Comment: Near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34135189/861716